# How can I watch videos in their own window?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, youtube, greasemonkey, vimeo

I'm sick and tired of watching youtube/vimeo/etc videos in my browser, and not being able to use the browser otherwise whilst doing so. What are my options for opening the embedded video in their own (chromeless) window, in a similar fashion to [Mozilla Prism](http://labs.mozilla.com/2007/10/prism/), or otherwise getting out of the way? Staying topmost would be handy too.

Thanks guys, Ehtyar.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the firefox plugin called "UNPLUG" to grab the video right from the website itself.

Unplug is handy however there are a number of applications that do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks Axxmasterr. I already have (more than one, for some reason) method of downloading the video. I would specifically like to *watch* it, but be able to browse concurrently. It would be best if I could do it in-browser, so I wouldn't have to bother with a media player as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'm blind.

It appears there has been a button at YouTube for some time that allows you to create a popup containing the video. My bad guys, voted to close.

[image: Popup Button]

Comment: You don't have to close it just because you've answered the question yourself. I recommend keeping it for posterity.

Comment: I didn't really consider it an answer, given that the question would not have been necessary in the first place if I'd used my eyes. I'd feel especially guilty marking this post as the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I use [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) and [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/). DownloadHelper is a Firefox extension that detects any media (flash video, wmv, whatever) and you can simply click to download it. When download starts, I tell mplayer to play the file. You can use any standalone player, of course, but MPlayer shines here because it plays anything so you don't have to think which player to use for that type of file.